# Stash with timestamps and custom written module

Tags: stash, module, time, mustash

I'm having a difficult time figuring this out.

There's a section in a website with events. Visitors can vote for these events, 24 hours before and after it happens. Longer before that, it has a 'attend'-button. Afterwards, it shows the average score.

As I always do, I use Croxton's stash plugin. This section, ofcourse, shouldn't be stashed.

So, at first, I had this:

`<div>
  {if {current_time format="%U"} - {event_time format="%U"} < -86400}
    {facebook_link}
  {/if}
  {if {current_time format="%U"} - {event_time format="%U"} < 86400 && {current_time format="%U"} - {event_time format="%U"} > -86400}
    <p>Voting open</p>
  {/if}
  {if {current_time format="%U"} - {event_time format="%U"} > 86400}
    <p style="color: black;">{exp:bol_voting:stats entry="{event_id}"}</p>
  {/if}
</div>`

Now, ofcourse, because these sections get stashed, the time-checks don't matter. If we reach the time-frame in which people can vote, nothing will happen. Also, the eventual average score returned by bol_voting will be stashed.

I didn't want that, so I wrapped it in a `{stash:nocache}` wrapper. All my variables, as well as my custom bol_voting module, don't get parsed anymore (event_time and facebook_link).

Anyone can save me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carefully "unescape" the variables you want to be cached, so e.g.

```
{stash:nocache}
<div>
  {if {current_time format="%U"} - {/stash:nocache}{event_time format="%U"}{stash:nocache} < -86400}
    {/stash:nocache}{facebook_link}{stash:nocache}
  {/if}
  {if {current_time format="%U"} - {/stash:nocache}{event_time format="%U"}{stash:nocache} < 86400 && {current_time format="%U"} - {/stash:nocache}{event_time format="%U"}{stash:nocache} > -86400}
    <p>Voting open</p>
  {/if}
  {if {current_time format="%U"} - {/stash:nocache}{event_time format="%U"}{stash:nocache} > 86400}
    <p style="color: black;">{exp:bol_voting:stats entry="{/stash:nocache}{event_id}{stash:nocache}"}</p>
  {/if}
</div>
{/stash:nocache}
```